# Mobile authentication using AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

like Google provide [FCM (firebase cloud messaging)](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/) for phone authentication, which send OTP to client device and authenticate the user mobile number.

[image]

Is there anything like that in amazon web service ? by which i can perform phone authentication from android device using mobile number.

Comment: yes it does have

Comment: how can i implement such phone authentication using aws ?

Comment: please check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**AWS** does have phone number verification, like one `firebase` have in your console goto

> Cognito => under general settings click **MFA and verifications**

There you can find options to enable or disable, you can send default message with OTP or you can even edit the message.

For customizing message you can goto

> Cognito => under general settings click **Message Customization**

For more details about this you can check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-email-phone-verification.html) and also [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html).

Comment: i started following your site which say
1. **setup development environent** step done perfectly (in cmd **amplify** **configure** command executed)
2. in **Set Up Your Backend** step , (in cmd **amplify init** command executed) it ask me for default editor and i selected sublime as a default editor and i hit enter. after that it only blinking cursor, not proceeding further. what should i do now ?
[here is screenshot of executed command](https://ibb.co/jjyTnK)

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong, you should follow the steps for android setup, what i think you are doing for web ,follow this link [From Aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/tutorial-android-aws-mobile-notes-auth.htm)

Comment: @PriteshVishwakarma and I think i answered your core question, which was about if that's possible with AWS

Comment: i follow the document for android , [here is url for it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#android-java) , it has same step which i followed

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/tutorial-android-aws-mobile-notes-auth.html)

Comment: And also, as i have answered your core question, please accept the answer so it may help others in future

Comment: after a lots of research i think , aws app auth provide phone verification with username/email and password not only for mobile number like whatsapp and hike have.